# vim remove whitespaces after preceding tabs

Tags: regex, vim, whitespace, vi

Can I remove tabs except indentations in vim? I.e. do not delete tabs on the beginning of each lines.

Here is an example where `\t` represents a tab:

```
SELECT \t\t col1, col2 \t
\t  SELECT  \t\t\t col1 \t\t col2
\t\t    SELECT  \t\t\t col1 \t\t col2
```

I want to delete all white spaces in my file except the tabs which is used for indentations as follows:

```
SELECT col1, col2
\t  SELECT col1, col2
\t\t    SELECT col1, col2
```

Comment: I'm completely confused as to WHICH tabs you need removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/[^\t]\zs\t\+//g
```

`[^\t]` matches anything other than a tab, `\zs` resets the start of the match, and `\t\+` matches 1 or more tabs. Thus, all tabs following any non-tab character (i.e. not at the beginning of the line) are removed.

Answer (score 0):

`\(^\t*\)\@<= \s*`

Here is what this means:

- `\(^\t*\)` is a series of indenting tabs
- `\@<=` means that what follows should be preceded by a series of indenting tabs
- `\s*` is a space optionally followed by more whitespace